# Set user in PlatformEventSubscriberConfig

Tags: apex

I am creating a new Platform Event Subscriber Config like this one, by using the Metadata API on a sandbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlatformEventSubscriberConfig xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <platformEventConsumer>UpdateLocationHook</platformEventConsumer>
    <batchSize>25</batchSize>
    <masterLabel>UpdateLocationHookConfig</masterLabel>
    <user>user@example.com.sandbox123</user>
</PlatformEventSubscriberConfig>
```

The question is... what will happen when I upload it via a Changeset? Will Salesforce update the user with the production one when deploying?

Thank you!
Regards,

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, sorry. 

Comment: So what did you do?

Answer (score 4):

Although the Salesforce Metadata API has a section on [Maintaining User References](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_user_references.htm) that says:

> For example, when you copy data to a sandbox, the fields containing usernames from the production organization are altered to include the sandbox name. In a sandbox named test, the username user@acme.com becomes user@acme.com.test. When you deploy the metadata in the sandbox to another organization, the test in the username is ignored.

This does not appear to work when deploying `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` (as of V52).

Using your example:

```
<user>user@example.com.sandbox123</user>
```

| Source Org (or VCS) | Target org | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user@example.com.sandbox123 | user@example.com.sandbox456 | In field: User - no User named user@example.com.sandbox123 found |
| user@example.com.sandbox123 | user@example.com | In field: User - no User named user@example.com.sandbox123 found |
| user@example.com | user@example.com.sandbox123 | In field: User - no User named user@example.com found |

To workaround this (non scratch org world), I used multiple branches corresponding to each target org where each branch had the correct username for each `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` and then deployed from that branch as needed.

> UPDATE 2022-06, If you have access to Gearset or possibly other DevOps tools, you can use the devops tool's "environment variables" to change strings in your source metadata to what they need to be in the target org. This avoids the multiple branch solution

Note that if you create a sandbox from PROD or clone a sandbox, the target sandbox will have the correct `<user>` for that environment's `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`.